# Notify SIP proxy call has ended

Tags: sip

The SIP "BYE" message is usually delivered from one SIP user agent to the other directly if the call is finished. How then can a SIP proxy, switch or exchange monitor if a call has ended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a proxy is interested in a call - in particular, it wants to know about BYEs - it requests its addition to the SIP route by adding a [`Record-Route`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-20.30) header.

The SIP RFC has [some example call flows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-16.12.1) illustrating the use of the header, but briefly, dialog-establishing requests (like `INVITE`, `REFER`, etc.) en route to the callee pass through various proxies. These add themselves to the *route set* of the dialog. When the callee constructs its response - or sends its own in-dialog request - it adds these servers' URIs to the messages it sends as `Route` headers. (I'm skipping some hairy details around `Route` headers and the `Request-URI` and RFC 2543 compatibility.)

Alternatively, a UA may be configured to use a certain chain of proxies: when it sends its INVITE, it will use `Route` headers (and the `Request-URI`) to force the message to travel a particular route.

Comment: And if you are not implementing your own proxy but trying to configure one, the option you should be looking for is technically "dialog stateful", sometimes colloquially "call stateful" mode beyond "transaction stateful".

Comment: I am implementing my own proxy. If I use the Record-Route header, will this mean more responsibility of the proxy in addition to just rediriecting the BYE message?

Comment: Nothing special, just the usual responsibilities like via handling. The responsibility is in the form of availability: An outage of such a proxy disrupts the signaling of ongoing calls. (reINVITEs, DTMF in INFO, etc.) Losing BYE messages can ruin your billing if not done right.

Comment: Also note that your billing can be screwed up by the SIP endpoints simply going away and never sending (or responding to) a BYE.  (Loss of power, loss of connectivity, etc.)  Often VoIP services use some method to periodically sample if the call is still alive using no-change re-INVITE or some other mechanism.  You could also monitor both directions of media streams and decide that if "too long" has gone without media in one direction that the call has been lost.  However, this method will fail in some valid use-cases.

Comment: You can increase the reliability of your billing by using a B2BUA - instead of a proxy, you have a user agent that "proxies" signalling & media. That way you don't have the missing BYE problem... but it can be tricky to implement such a thing properly.